# WebSphere - preventing DoS - limiting web container threads per IP (client)

Tags: security, websphere

WebSphere provides WebContainer max threads size - that allows it to control number of web requests handled at the same time.

I am wondering if WebSphere allows similiar things per incoming IP address. That is, does WebSphere allows you to configure per each different incoming IPs not more than , for example, 10, WebContainer threads.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a capability to restrict the number of threads per client (based on IP or other characteristics).

DoS is better handled by other systems upstream.